# Is the set of non-terminating binary decimals in [0,1] lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

I think it is true, but I don't know where to start...Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: My recall of measure theory is not great, but isn't it a closed set and therefore automatically measurable?

Comment: @RobinSaunders , but why it is closed? Could you please give me a sketch of proof? Thanks!

Comment: Ah - you're not including binary decimals which terminate, so it's not closed. Sorry! Nevertheless, I think if you include terminating decimals you should get a closed set of measure 0, any subset of which would then also have measure 0.

Comment: Note: I assumed that by "binary decimals" you meant numbers which, when written in decimal (base ten), consist of only 0s and 1s. André's answer below assumes that you meant any number, which just happens to be written in binary (base two). Could you clarify which one you meant?

Comment: @RobinSaunders, what I am asking is of base two. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The set $T$ of numbers in our interval that have a **terminating** binary representation is countably infinite. Hence $T$ is measurable. It follows that its complement in $[0,1]$ is measurable.

Comment: That's such a terse and nice proof! Thanks, @Andre!